# What is the difference between debugging a background job (with one step) and debugging a program?

Tags: abap

I have a background job with only one step. I want to debug that job, so I used the  '`JDBG`' command in `SM37` transaction.

When I do this, the job just runs again, updating the database tables.

So, in this case, what is the difference between debugging the background job in `SM37` and running the program with a break point?
(except for the `SY-BATCH` system variable, it is not relevant in this case )

I wanted to debug a background job in the productive system, but using the `JDBG` method does not seem to help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Background jobs cannot simply be debugged. They start at a scheduled time, not interactively, are usually run by a different user, such as `RFCREMOTE`, have system settings like `sy-batch = 'X'` and don't have access to the SAP GUI. Setting a breakpoint in a program that's run in background mode won't do anything at all.

`JDBG` simulates what happens when a program is started by the background job scheduler. [It effectively runs a copy of the program, not the original program itself.](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3772414) If the program doesn't care for batch settings and user, this will probably not look any different from running the program interactively.

`JDBG` thus especially does not enable you to "hook into" a job that's already scheduled in a production system.

Comment: Hmm it doesn't "run a copy of the program", it runs the same program (not a copy) with the same parameters as the job, but interactively as you say (like `SUBMIT ... AND RETURN` with the specificity that `SY-BATCH` is set to 'X' as Ovidiu Pocnet said). And so, we can't say that "the job just runs again" dixit Ovidiu Pocnet.

Comment: There are background jobs which are launched from SAP transactions and cannot be started again because there are some parameters stored in the database just for one job. For instance, "mass processing" transactions from the FI-CA module of SAP ERP, like FPMA, ETHIM_TAX, ... One solution is to prevent the job(s) from running by activation the job interception (program INITXBP2 + transaction CRIT).

Answer (score 4):

You can use Transaction SM50 - Process Overview. SM50 is used to monitor and manage work processes.

Via **Administration->Program->Debugging** you can debug the program which is executed in the choosen work process.